# Parse Json using Json Net and C# to fill a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have a Json something like below:
    [{"Example temp" :  "value"}, {"Example Default" : "", "selected": true}]

I need to fill a dropdown say for example:
Dropdown should contain values : Example temp 
                                 Example Default

And Example Default should be the default selected value,

I tried below code:

```
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonstring);

foreach (JObject jObject in jArray.Children<JObject>())
{
   foreach (JProperty jProperty in jObject.Properties())
    {
     string name = jProperty.Name.Trim();
      string value = jProperty.Value.ToString().Trim();
        drpValues.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(name, value));
     }
 }
```

But "selected" also comes as a dropdown value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

-PT

Comment: Can you change your json format? It would be easier if you can change it to something like `[{"Text" : "Example temp", "Value" : "SomeValue"}, {"Text" : "Example Default", "Value" : "", "selected": true}]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ekad! how do I fill the dropdown with this json, please help! I used this json with my dropdown filling logic and now I have my dropdown values as Example temp, Value, Text, Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's only one default value, this code should work

```
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonStr);

bool isDefault;
string defaultValue;
foreach (JObject jObject in jArray.Children<JObject>())
{
    isDefault = false;

    // check if current jObject contains a property named "selected"
    // and if the value is true
    JProperty p = jObject.Properties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "selected");
    if (p != null && (bool)p.Value == true)
    {
        isDefault = true;
    }

    foreach (JProperty jProperty in jObject.Properties())
    {
        string name = jProperty.Name.Trim();
        string value = jProperty.Value.ToString().Trim();

        if (name != "selected")
        {
            drpValues.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(name, value));
            if (isDefault)
            {
                defaultValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

// set the dropdown selected item
RadComboBoxItem itemToSelect = drpValues.FindItemByValue(defaultValue);
itemToSelect.Selected = true;
```

Comment: This looks great! Looking for any answer without changing the Json, Want to be less Json for the user for easy update and less confusion, Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: can this be done without changing the Json? Thank you!

Comment: see the edited answer, I think that's what you're looking for.